# Apache POI and autofit XSSFRow heigth by content

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have fixed width of column and need autofit row height with **apache POI**, but I can't find working desicion for it. I tried [this decision](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Autosize-row-for-HSSF-library-td2308264.html), but it doesn't work with this text

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
> eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua

[image]

Column width is *33.00 (236 pixels)* and cell in table with *wrap text* property. I can change row height only if content height more that existing height of row.

So, I would like to ask if there is any method or desicions for autosize the row height by content?

```java
private float calculateRowLinesForText(Font cellFont, float columnWidthInPoints, String value) {
        java.awt.Font currFont = new java.awt.Font(cellFont.getFontName(), 0, cellFont.getFontHeightInPoints());

        FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);

        int lineCnt = 0;
        for (String partValue : value.split("\n")) {
            AttributedString attrStr = new AttributedString(partValue);
            attrStr.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, currFont);
            LineBreakMeasurer measurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(attrStr.getIterator(), frc);

            while (measurer.getPosition() < partValue.length()) {
                int nextPos = measurer.nextOffset(columnWidthInPoints);
                lineCnt++;
                measurer.setPosition(nextPos);
            }
        }

        return lineCnt;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the row is not within a merged region, then it will auto height if the height is not set explicitly. So you need set height to undefined (-1). See [Row.setHeight](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#setHeight-short-):

> Set the row's height or set to ff (-1) for undefined/default-height.

Complete example:

Source `Excel.xlsx`:

[image]

Code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil;

public class CreateExcelCellWrapText {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./Excel.xlsx"));

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  
  Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
  Cell cell = row.getCell(2); // cell C3
  cell.setCellValue("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua");
  CellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(cell, CellUtil.WRAP_TEXT, true); // make sure wrap text is set.
  row.setHeight((short)-1); // set row heigth undefined so it is auto heigth

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./ExcelNew.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Result `ExcelNew.xlsx`:

[image]

If you don't know which rows must be auto height and need to decide that from the required height, then you need calculating the required height dependent of cell width, text and used font. That's a challenging task. See [How to get the needed height of a multi line rich-text field (any font, any font size) having defined width using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420801/how-to-get-the-needed-height-of-a-multi-line-rich-text-field-any-font-any-font/45437726#45437726) for a possible solution.

Comment: Yes, I saw this decision. I need set this only for rows which has content more that current height. If row has 53 height and text "B1" that I not change this. And I need iterate by all rows.

Comment: So you don't know which rows must be auto height and need to decide that from the required height? So you need calculating the required height? That's a challenging task. But see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420801/how-to-get-the-needed-height-of-a-multi-line-rich-text-field-any-font-any-font/45437726#45437726.

Comment: Your decision works well. Can you explain, please, how work this magic?) Why we use 72? And how I need do it if I develop server application? 
`(72f/ppi)`

Comment: @Andrew Sulyz : The `72/ppi` is needed to convert from `px` to `pt` as we need `pt` to set the height in `Excel`. A `pt` is an inch point and there are 72pt in an inch. The `ppi` is `px` per inch in screen resoluntion. And my solution uses a `Swing` `JTextPane` to render the text. So it needs a `GUI` in background.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I add for this answer this answer for wrap long words.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666727/wrap-long-words-in-jtextpane-java-7