# Row height calculate algorithm

Tags: excel, algorithm, apache-poi, row-height

What is the algorithm for calculating row height in Excel? I need to output the exact value, I have found other solutions but there is a slight error

I saw this article but it has an error [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420801/how-to-get-the-needed-height-of-a-multi-line-rich-text-field-any-font-any-font/45437726#45437726)

or if there is a library in Java, you can say that

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA? Could use Range.RowHeight. You could make a custom function in VBA to return row height using the Range.Row height property. I cannot think of a way to get at row height using only built in functions.

Comment: thanks.no i don't use vba.
I want to prepare excel in java, using apache tools, since auto height is not given to merged cell in excel, I want to set it by myself.
I need a formula that determines the height based on text, font, cell weight