# How to check if text fits into cell?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using **apache poi 3.17** for generating *.xlsx files.

For a reason I don't know, the **setWrapText(true)** (merged cells) function of the class **CellStyleDesc** does not trigger the resizing of the row's height as it should be.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Questions will get more activity if you show a [mcve]. [edit] the question to tell us what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what went wrong.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45387206/how-to-increase-the-height-of-the-excel-row-using-apache-poi-having-merged-cell/45388037#45388037 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420801/how-to-get-the-needed-height-of-a-multi-line-rich-text-field-any-font-any-font/45437726#45437726